# INSERT INTO or UPDATE with two conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

This problem seems easy at first sight, but I simply have not found a solution that is reasonable time wise.

Consider a table with the following characteristics:

```
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
name INTEGER
values1 INTEGER
values2 INTEGER
dates DATE
```

Every day, N amount of new rows are generated, for dates into the future, and with the 'name' coming from a finite list. I would like to insert a new row when there is new data, but if there is already a row with 'name' and 'dates', simply update it.

Please note that a current proposed solution of an SPROC that checks the conditional is not feasible, as this is data being pushed from another language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that is what `insert on duplicate key update` is for.

The Manual page for it is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

The trick is that the table needs to have a unique key (can be a composite) so that the `clash` of doing an insert can be detected. As such, the update to occur on that row, otherwise an insert. It can be a primary key, of course.

In your case, you could have a composite key such as

```
unique key(theName,theDate)
```

If the row is already there, the `clash` is detected, and the update happens.

### Here is a complete example

```
create table myThing
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    name int not null,
    values1 int not null,
    values2 int not null,
    dates date not null,
    unique key(name,dates) -- <---- this line here is darn important
);

insert myThing(name,values1,values2,dates) values (777,1,1,'2015-07-11') on duplicate key update values2=values2+1;
insert myThing(name,values1,values2,dates) values (778,1,1,'2015-07-11') on duplicate key update values2=values2+1;
-- do the 1st one a few more times:
insert myThing(name,values1,values2,dates) values (777,1,1,'2015-07-11') on duplicate key update values2=values2+1;
insert myThing(name,values1,values2,dates) values (777,1,1,'2015-07-11') on duplicate key update values2=values2+1;
insert myThing(name,values1,values2,dates) values (777,1,1,'2015-07-11') on duplicate key update values2=values2+1;
```

show results

```
select * from myThing;
+----+------+---------+---------+------------+
| id | name | values1 | values2 | dates      |
+----+------+---------+---------+------------+
|  1 |  777 |       1 |       4 | 2015-07-11 |
|  2 |  778 |       1 |       1 | 2015-07-11 |
+----+------+---------+---------+------------+
```

As expected, insert on duplicate key update works, just 2 rows.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy:

- Create a unique key on the columns to check
- Use the INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE construct