# Mysql count changes on a row

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I INSERT on unique but UPDATE on duplicate.

Now I'd like to count the times a row get changed/updated. Is this possible to do in the same query?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table(
                      column1,
                      column2)
                VALUES(
                      value1,
                      value2)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                      column1 = VALUES(column1),
                      column2 = VALUES(column2),
                      column3 = column3+1";  //SOMETHING LIKE THIS?
```

**UPDATE**
Actually this seems to work as is!

Comment: No. It's not possible.

Comment: @Strawberry ok. Thanks. Do you have any thoughts on how you have solved it?

Comment: I may be confused but why doesn't it work with `IODKU` with merely incrementing `column3` ? And col3 on insert is just say a 1 ? You need a unique key to generate the clash such that `IODKU` will even work

Comment: Maybe take a look at triggers... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: to visualize it with `IODKU` with see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32468519) example i wrote up. I would be happy to write yours up in its entirety, but a schema of the table is required to see if it is even possible

Comment: @Drew Thank you. Your example shows me this code actually works. Please combind with your answer and i will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as requested,

If your schema has a unique key of any kind (such as a Primary Key, or any other unique key, composite or not), then `Insert On Duplicate Key Update` a.k.a. `IODKU` will work, as I see it.

A simple case to test against would be to insert a 1 into column3 or in the case of the Update firing, incrementing column3.

An example of `IODKU` can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32468519) that closely follows what I think you are doing, yet it has a unique composite key for that gent's question.

Please note, without a unique key that would create a unique key clash, `IODKU` will not work. It is such a clash that causes the Update part of `IODKU` to succeed as desired. Meaning, without such a unique key, you merely get another row added.

I say this because many people try it without such a key in place in the schema, then wonder why another row appears against their wishes.

Mysql manual page on [Insert on Duplicate Key Update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 0):

My tought would be to create a new table logs where you would add a row each time you insert/update with the query.
To see the result just use a COUNT function on the logs table.

Comment: I´m sorry this is not possible, in my case!