# Batch insert with select statment mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to do a batch of insert to mysql. I got this code to work without the inner select question. [How do I do a bulk insert in mySQL using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js) But when i add the select i get "ER_PARSE_ERROR".

```
var arr = [[1, '123456789', '2000-01-01', 1],[2, '123456789', '2000-01-02', 1],[3, '123456789', '2000-01-03', 1]];

objConn.query("INSERT INTO stats (`name`, `phone`, `dayOfCall` , `calls`) \
                VALUES ((SELECT `name` as myname FROM `contact` WHERE `id` = ? \
                LIMIT 1), ?, ?, ?)",
            [arr],
            function (err, row, fields){
                if(err)
                    logger.info(err);
            }
        );
```

Comment: The forms are `INSERT .... VALUES (), (), ();` or `INSERT ... SELECT ...;` NOT `INSERT ... VALUES ((SELECT...`

Comment: @Uueerdo write it up

Comment: Yes please, would it work if the select has a WHERE id = ? to it?

Comment: @Drew I would, but trying to keep focused on other matters right now.

Comment: @KristerJohansson Yes, the WHERE and even the LIMIT should still work as is; though I am still wondering where you are expecting the `phone`, `day`, and even `call` values to come from.

Comment: also, the data you insert has to clash/trigger/violate (whatever you want to call it) ... a unique key, so that your IODKU works. If you don't have that under your belt, I can point you to one of my answers. In fact, here is a link [Right Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32468519). It does an increment on a column to show it works. "It works" meaning a new row is not inserted, rather updated, and proves it by incrementing a column value on that row.

Comment: So, write a question at 2am is not werry good :) Fix the sql some more, but the problem still remains.